# Regular expression for unique number.

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need a regular expression that validate an unique value. It has a unique 9 digit number, in the format 000000000A (where 0 is a digit and A is a letter). Only allows letter "V" or "X" for last string.

I can do it for digits but not sure how to modify for last string.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{9}$
```

Hope somebody may help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use character class `[VX]`, it'll match a single character from it.

```
^[1-9][0-9]{8}[VX]$
```

Or, `OR` condition as follow

```
^[1-9][0-9]{8}(V|X)$
```

---

**Update:**

To match the alphabets case-insensitively, use `i` flag or the lowercase characters can also be added in class

```
^[1-9][0-9]{8}[VvXx]$
```

Comment: to check case sensitive for `X.V`. I tried it something like this `^[1-9][0-9]{8}(V|X)$/i` but it doesn't work

Comment: @user3733831 Use case-insensitive flag `/^[1-9][0-9]{8}[VX]$/i` or you can also use `[VvXx]`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try something simpler (unless the leading number cannot be 0)

```
\d{9}[VX]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `d{9}` ? `/\d{9}(V|X)/` seems easier.

```
var test = "qwerty000000000Xqwerty";

console.log(test.match(/\d{9}(V|X)/));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u5gmfjeL/1/ - matches `830363670V` as well.

case insensitive add `/i` -> /`\d{9}(V|X)/i` -> http://jsfiddle.net/u5gmfjeL/2/

Comment: how to modify to match case sensitive for `X, V`

Comment: @user3733831 I guess you mean `case-insensitive`, you can use `i` flag

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{8}[VX]$
```

Or more generically if the suffix were more than one character you could use groups. As it appears you are using POSIX Extended Regular Expression (ERE) syntax, you can also use parenthesis for groups, like:

```
^[1-9][0-9]{8}(V|X)$
```

[Link to ERE syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799)

[Link to JavaScript Regex standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects)

Comment: The question is tagged JavaScript and PHP.  Obviously it can't be both, but neither of those is the same as POSIX ERE.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't notice the tags. I just saw the {8} and could see it must be somewhere in the Extended RE family. Looks like JavaScript REs are a kind of degenerate Perl-compatible RE, which should be a pure superset of EREs though. Who knows what PHP is.